# How to use API keys to Authenticate Requests From an API

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I'm Trying to get the latitude and longitude of an address using the Geocoding API.
That's my code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(TrackingOrder.this, jsonObject + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                                .getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location")
                                .get("lat").toString();
                        String lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results"))
                                .getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location")
                                .get("lng").toString();
```

The Problem is I'm receiving "Access Denied" response

```
 "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
       "results" : [],
       "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
    }
```

I Generate an API Key, restrict it, link it with my android app (Name,SHA)and enable Geocoding API
I try to call this request on the Browser the same problem(the same Output):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: Your code appears to lack the code that makes the request and evidently this lacks the required API key. You will need a Google Project and have enabled the Maps API and created an API (suitablly restricted). The API key can be plugged into the request generator to authenticate your code. Have a look at Google's extensive [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) where this is all explained.

Comment: thank you @DazWilkin I did as you said but the same problem appears I try this URL:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY` But it gave me the same output on the browser:
`"error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
       "results" : [],
       "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED}`

Comment: @DazWilkin
Is there a possibility that it doesn't work because this service isn't free?
Or may I have to convert the account to a billing account?

Comment: Yes, that may be the case. The [Geocoding API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/geocoding-backend.googleapis.com) does not appear to provide a free tier (although there's usage for free when you pay)

Comment: Ok so that's it thank you @DazWilkin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue calling geocode via application. So wanted to ensure the same was repeated via postman. The result confirmed, that we need to ensure steps are followed on Google API mandated restrictions as basic.

Additional security using Current secret Key is also given. If you don't want to use the additional current secret you can disable it or delete it.

### Errors Reported

Case-1
"error_message": "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to [http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"](http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account%22),
"results": [],
"status": "REQUEST_DENIED"

Case-2
{
"error_message": "API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API.",
"results": [],
"status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Remove Restriction on going to --> https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis
As in below options.

### Application restrictions

An application restriction controls which websites,IP addresses,or applications can use your API key.

You can set one application restriction per key.
1)None
2)HTTP referrers (web sites) -->  //I chose this one for my case.
3)IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)
4)Android apps
5)iOS apps

Website Restrictions
Restrict key usage requests to the specified websites.
eg: give https://:port/ or https://

If left blank, your API key will accept requests from any website.

I hope this helps.
Regards,
RKD